# Input multiple values separated by Comma as Input parameter in Jenkins

Tags: unix, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins world.I am trying to create a job in Jenkins where i need to input multiple file names separated by comma as input parameter.And, catch these file names in  Unix command inside Execute shell area to delete the same using rm -rf command(these files are available in some specific path).How can we use Jenkins to do the same?
Files names are like:

18_07_2015.log
22_07_2015.log
29_07_2015.log

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use String parameters in your jenkins job:

[image]

Then add the param to your shell script:

```
   rm -rf ${FILE_PARAM}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's really helpful.